# Pytorch generate polynomials of a vector

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor

```
x = [4,5,6]
```

I want to transform this tensor `x` into the following tensor:

```
[[   4,    5,    6],
 [4**2, 5**2, 6**2],
 [4**3, 5**3, 6**3]]
```

where each row is a higher degree polynomial than the previous.

I tried searching Pytorch documentation and found the [`repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html) function. This allows me to generate multiple rows of the same values, which I can then use a for-loop or map to modify the values.

I understand that using a for loop can solve this, but I am wondering if there is already an inbuilt function in Pytorch that lets me do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power function [`torch.pow`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.pow.html#torch.pow) also accepts tensors as the exponent argument. Start by expanding your input tensor `x`, column-wise:

```
>>> x = x[:,None].expand(-1,3)
tensor([[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]])
```

Then define your exponents as a range tensor:

```
>>> a = torch.arange(1,4)
tensor([1, 2, 3])
```

And compute your power tensor:

```
>>> x.pow(a).T
tensor([[  4,   5,   6],
        [ 16,  25,  36],
        [ 64, 125, 216]])
```